# Cannot assign to property of 'localVc' which is a get-only object?

Tags: swift, objective-c

Like the code showed below, why swift cannot allow to assign a property  of a readonly object? The readonly object 'localVc' have the set-write property "refreshGesture".

```
public protocol HVSHomeVideoChildProtocol {
    var refreshGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer! {get set}
}

class HVSHomeLocalVideoController: HVSHomeVideoChildProtocol {

    public var refreshGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
}


typealias HVSHomeVideoController = (UIViewController & HVSHomeVideoChildProtocol)

@objc(HSAVideoHomeViewController)
class HSAVideoHomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var refreshGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer!
    let singleLocalVc = HVSHomeLocalVideoController.init()  
    var localVc: HVSHomeVideoController {
        return singleLocalVc
    }


    public override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        refreshGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer.init(target: self, action: #selector(refreshGestureAction(sender:)))
        localVc.refreshGesture = refreshGesture
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public protocol HVSHomeVideoChildProtocol {
    var refreshGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer! {get set}
}
```

To

```
public protocol HVSHomeVideoChildProtocol : AnyObject {
    var refreshGesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer! {get set}
}
```